# Strongswan IKEv2 vpn on Windows 10 client. I'm getting "policy match error"

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, debian, vpn, strongswan

my log file:

```
Jan 16 22:10:46 ip-172-26-4-200 charon: 05[CFG] selecting proposal:
Jan 16 22:10:46 ip-172-26-4-200 charon: 05[CFG]   no acceptable ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM found
Jan 16 22:10:46 ip-172-26-4-200 charon: 05[CFG] received proposals: IKE:AES_CBC_128/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/ECP_256
Jan 16 22:10:46 ip-172-26-4-200 charon: 05[CFG] configured proposals: IKE:AES_GCM_16_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/ECP_256
Jan 16 22:10:46 ip-172-26-4-200 charon: 05[IKE] local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
Jan 16 22:10:46 ip-172-26-4-200 charon: 05[IKE] remote host is behind NAT
```

What should I set by [Set-VpnConnectionIPsecConfiguratio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/set-vpnconnectionipsecconfiguration)n in windows10? I can't figure out.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault :) Please edit your question to have more detail, and ideally fix up the formatting (I'll do a little to help). For example: what are you connecting to? How are the source and target currently configured? Which log file is that, client or server?

Answer (score 0):

The client is proposing AES in CBC mode with HMAC-SHA2-256 as integrity protection, while the server is configured for AES in GCM mode (AEAD, combined-mode, which includes encryption and integrity protection). Change **either** of these to make the connection work.

On the client, use `VpnConnectionIPsecConfiguration ... -EncryptionMethod GCMAES128 ...` to make it use 128-bit AES-GCM for IKEv2.

On the server, you could change the IKE proposals by either adding another one with `aes128` and `sha256` (AEAD and classic algorithms have to be in separate proposals, e.g. `aes128gcm16-prfsha256-ecp256, aes128-sha256-ecp256`), clients are then free to use one or the other, or replace `aes128gcm16` with `aes128-sha256` in the existing proposal.

You might have a similar issue with the ESP proposal, which you can fix similarly (on the Windows client, `-CipherTransformConstants GCMAES128` configures AES-GCM for ESP).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is Windows client uses a different Proposal when rekeying. Which is why so many are having disconnects when the client timeouts (7.6 hours) and rekeys. I have yet to pin down that proposal.